# In suitescript's user events, What controls how data is serialized on beforeLoad and afterSubmit events?

Tags: oracle, netsuite, suitescript2.0

There is a new requirement on my company and I'm learning Suitescript in order to integrate it with another existing system.

Reading the documentation I found out about Suitescript's user events and they fit the purpose, but I'm having issues understanding what controls or how is decided how field values are serialized on the `scriptContext.oldRecord`/`scriptContext.newRecord` .

For instance, boolean fields are included on the object as either `someField: "T"` or `someField:"F"` instead of `someField: true`

Also date formats are inconsistent, sometimes they include seconds (like: 30/9/2021 17:06:00), sometimes they don't (30/9/2021 17:06), sometimes single-digit day/month are prepended with a zero, sometimes they don't.

Another detail is the `SalesOrder` status, is injected translated into spanish (system preference) but I don't see where the status `Sales Order: Billed` becomes `"Facturado"` (spanish for Billed)

Could anybody shed some light of where can I see this conventions or preferences?

Thanks in advance

PD: I been looking on the other scripts and there is no aparent logic for this differences

Answer (score 0):

This is a Utility function I created for not having to deal with `Which boolean today?` anymore.  I work with english code, so I am not sure how to deal with translations in the system.  For that, I would maybe look in to [this section of SuiteAnswers](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/87148) more??

```
/**
 *
 * @name setTrueBoolean
 * @description Returns a true boolean response
 * @function
 * @scope public
 * @param {String|boolean} str - String to convert to true boolean
 * @return {boolean}
 */
const setTrueBoolean = (str) => {
    if (typeof str === 'boolean') return str;
    let res = 'str is not true or false';
    try {
        switch (true) {
            case /[f][a]?.*/gi.test(str):
                res = false;
                break;
            case /[t][r]?.*/gi.test(str):
                res = true;
                break;
            default:
                throw res;
        }
        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        log.error({
            title: 'setTrueBoolean ERROR',
            details: { str, res, err },
        });
        return str;
    }
};
```